# Best way to apply Style to every other div when an outside style sheet that I have no access to is coming into play?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bxslider

I'm using BXSlider and attempting to change the background of every even iteration of the slider. The problem is that a css sheet that I do not have access to is affecting all sliders on the page.

Context-

```html
<div class="bx-wrapper">
  <div class="bx-viewport">
    <div class="bx-slider">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Bx-wrapper and Bx-viewport are added automatically via the bxslider library.

The css sheet (that I have no access to) has the background set to #fff-

```css
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {

    background: #fff;
  }
```

I am changing the background of the slider with -

```css
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport:nth-child(even){
 background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
 
}
```

My main problem is that the original #fff takes precedence and I can only see the above css working when I un-check that style in dev tools. What do you all think the best way to ensure that the above css takes precedence?

Comment: The CSS seems to work as it is?

Comment: Not sure if I'm explaining this well enough. It does work but the original css sheet that is already pushed to the server has the background set to #fff which is taking precedence over my nth-child(even) rule.

Comment: If I put all those rules to a same stylesheet, the :nth-child(even) works, no matter which rule comes first. Notice, that the indexing of the children in CSS starts from one.

Comment: Try adding `!important` to your custom rule.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm at a loss for why important isnt working either. @Teemu the original rule of #fff is found in a global style sheet that is automatically put in the header of each page across the website. I'm not sure why its still overtaking the nth-child even rule.

Comment: I suppose I understand the question, only that the rules in the example [are not mutual exclusive](https://jsfiddle.net/L4uqnd0m/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your style is just being overridden by the existing stylesheet, correct?

To give your style priority over the existing stylesheet, your CSS scoping should be as specific as possible and, if necessary, contain the `!important` property.

For example, instead of having...

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport:nth-child(even){
    background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
}
```

... you might want to try...

```
html body .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport:nth-child(even){    /*or whatever the full scope path to your elements would be*/
    background-color: rgb(245,245,245) !important;  
}
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ive actually been trying !important and it still doesnt seem to work which is super odd to me and what prompted me to post here. I'm really at a loss for why important is failing to force the new rule.

Comment: @JoeG Were you able to try making the selector scope more specific?
This usually does the trick when I'm styling existing webpages.